# SQL counter difficulties

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select maintitle, 
       firstprodyear, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT episode.episodeid) as TOTALEPISODES
from series
LEFT OUTER JOIN episode ON series.seriesid = episode.seriesid     
LEFT OUTER JOIN filmitem ON filmitem.filmid = episode.episodeid 
where firstprodyear =(select MIN(firstprodyear) from series)
group by maintitle, firstprodyear;
```

2/3s of the query works. I do get the title of the serie and earliest year. But it seems like the episode counter isn't working properly. For some episode I do get 15, 34 and somewhere 0. 
I would preciate for some guidance to make the episodecounter work as it should. Where have I missed?

Comment: What results would you expect to get? Can you include some sample data?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select maintitle, 
       min(firstprodyear) firstprodyear, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT episode.episodeid) as TOTALEPISODES
from series
LEFT OUTER JOIN episode ON series.seriesid = episode.seriesid     
/*LEFT OUTER JOIN filmitem ON filmitem.filmid = episode.episodeid */
group by maintitle;
```

Note: the link to filmitem appears to be unnecessary with the data selected.

Comment: Yes, I do think that the problem might be related with that. Notice that you are joining several tables using different IDs (instead of just using episode.episodeid). So, you might end up with tricky results.

Comment: I tried and the same thing happend. The seriesID is the foreign key for episode table, but also filmid from filmitem gives the episode.episodeid wich is it's primary key. I'm just apperently blind now, but thanks for the efforts :)

Answer (score 0):

Your query is returning the series that have `firstprodyear` equal to the earliest `firstprodyear` in the your database. You can think of the sub-select statement as returning a fixed number that is then used in the query.

For example, if the earliest series in your database is Days of Our Lives (`firstprodyear = 1965`), then you will get back the number of episodes in those series that also started in 1965.

You may also want to be more explicit about which table actually contains the `firstprodyear` field, though I'm assuming it's `series`.

Comment: Series(maintitle, firstprodyear, seriesID) ------ Episode(episodeID(primary ref filmitem), subtitle(wich we ignore), seriesid (ref filmitem), seriesid(foreign key ref seriesID)